# Are all arrays declared as a class variable supposed to be static?

Tags: java, arrays, class, object

I'm trying to write a code that increments an integer array which is declared as a class variable, separately using 2 different objects of the class.

```
class Foo {
    int n[];

    Foo(int n1[], int x, int y) {
        n = new int[]{0, 0, 0, 0};
        n1[0] = n1[0] + x;
        n1[1] = n1[1] + y;
        this.n = n1;
    }
}

public class stats {
    public static void print(Foo obj) {
        for (int i = 0; i < obj.n.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(obj.n[i]);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n[] = {1, 1, 1, 1};
        Foo a = new Foo(n, 1, 1);

        Foo b = new Foo(n, 2, 2);
        print(a);
        print(b);

    }
}
```

Expected Output:

```
2
2
1
1
3
3
1
1
```

Actual Output

```
4
4
1
1
4
4
1
1
```

Is there a reason as to why it is incrementing the array across the objects as a static variable, despite not declaring the variable as static? Like is every integer array declared as a class variable static? How would I go about getting the expected output?

Comment: `this.n = n1;` overwrites the field `n` with parameter `n1`'s array object.

Comment: Your `int n[];` declared in `class Foo` is **instance variable**, not class variable. Class variables are the ones declared with `static` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

The important part is `this.n = n1;`.
This means that both objects have a reference to the same array `n` which you created in your main method.

Answer (score 0):

In your `Foo` parameter you write new values into the `n1` parameter (which is the same array as referenced by `n` in your `main` method).

You allocate a new array in the constructor, but you never actually use it and overwrite the reference to it in the last line of the constructor with `this.n = n1`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that both `a` and `b` increment the same array is because you've passed `n` to both. The variable kept within the classes isn't an actual array but rather a memory reference to one. Therefore, since you've passed the same memory reference (`n`) to both objects, they are both modifying the same part of memory. It has little to nothing to do with static. If you want them both to have different arrays, you will have to create a copy of `n`, so that you have two arrays, seperate in memory.

Comment: Does it point to memory reference only for arrays? I've noticed when I use `this` with int it points to rather the value.

Comment: The memory reference case does not apply to int and char and other primitive types, because those types are immutable. If you pass an int to a function that modifies it, the int passed will be copied so that it retains its original value. For all objects however, variables actually refer to the memory allocated for the object on the stack.

Answer (score 0):

This because of a reference (not a copy) of your array is passed to the Foo's constructor.

In your main function:

Array is declared

```
int n[] = {1, 1, 1, 1};
```

// Next statement will change the value of n as {2,2,1,1}.And this array will saved inside Foo class

```
Foo a = new Foo(n, 1, 1);
```

//Now remember values of n in main method is {2,2,1,1}

```
Foo b = new Foo(n, 2, 2);  // Here n = {2,2,1,1}
```

After above statement n in main method becomes {4,4,1,1}